# PHP Array Sum with specific key and condition

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [6254] => Array
        (
            [check] => on
            [quantity] => 2
            [name] => Testing product_special One Size
            [total] => 66.0000
            [price] => 33.0000
        )

    [6255] => Array
        (
            [check] => on
            [quantity] => 1
            [name] => Testing card
            [total] => 80.85
            [price] => 33.0000
        )

)
```

Above is my array .

My Code

```
foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
    $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $key);
    echo "<pre>";
    // print_r(array_sum(array_column($value, 'price')));
    print_r($value);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
}
```

wanted to ask , how do i "specifically" add prices ? tried with

```
$totalprice += $value['price'];
```

is not working

---

array_sum(array_column($value, 'price'))  < this code fixed my problem

---

but there is a new question , what if need to check on "condition"

if "check" = on only able to sum , if there is no "check" ignore the array

Comment: your question is vague? which `key` are you referring to?

Comment: This `array_sum(array_column($value, 'price'))` should be working for you.

Comment: @ROOT thanks it work fine , then i have 1 more question . let say in my array have "check" , how to only sum the array if the "check" is on ? 
got 2 status , "on/off"

Comment: @greenboxgoolu, glade to help,  add your question to the post.

Comment: added my question to the bottom

Comment: You can do preg_replace. You can do array_column, but can't add an extra if condition for `on`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify regex pattern in $yourRegex variable.

```
$total= 0;
foreach($value as $key => $value){
    $yourRegex = '/\s+/';
    if(preg_match($yourRegex, '', $key)) {
        $total+= $value['price'];
    }
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is stored in `$value`, you should use `$totalprice += $value2['price'];` since `$value2` is an array itself.

Comment: but if i used $value2 ( it only used 1 array instead of multiple )

Comment: @greenboxgoolu No, you have foreach which loop through the $value, and for each element of this $value array, you extract the price with $value2['price']

Comment: $totalprice = 0;
        $totalprice += $value2['price'];
                
        echo "<pre>";
           
              print_r($totalprice);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;

if i used this it only take 1 line instead of multiple

Comment: @greenboxgoolu what is $key referring to in your code?!